# dictionary column operation counter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

‘fruit_classifier.csv’​ ​ is​ ​ a ​ ​ CSV​ ​ file​ ​ which​ ​ is​ ​ the​ ​ output​ ​ of​ ​ a ​ ​ program​ ​ which​ ​ classifies​ ​ images​ ​ into
different​ ​ kind​ ​ of​ ​ fruits.​ ​ Each​ ​ classification​ ​ is​ ​ scored​ ​ in​ ​ terms​ ​ of​ ​ percentage.​ ​ For​ ​ example,​ ​ image
‘a.jpg’​ ​ has​ ​ ​ a ​ ​ 99.18%​ ​ chance​ ​ it​ ​ is​ ​ a ​ ​ Pear,​ ​ 0.15%​ ​ chance​ ​ it​ ​ is​ ​ an​ ​ orange​ ​ etc.

he​ ​ first​ ​ new​ ​ row​ ​ to​ ​ be​ ​ added​ ​ must​ ​ show​ ​ the​ ​ percentage​ ​ of​ ​ images,​ ​ for​ ​ each​ ​ type​ ​ of​ ​ fruit,
where​ ​ the​ ​ detection​ ​ value​ ​ was​ ​ greater​ ​ than​ ​ 50%.​ ​ i.e.​ ​ if​ ​ out​ ​ of​ ​ 15​ ​ images,​ ​ if​ ​ Apples​ ​ had​ ​ 6 ​ ​ images
where​ ​ the​ ​ detection​ ​ value​ ​ was​ ​ greater​ ​ than​ ​ 50%,​ ​ you​ ​ need​ ​ to​ ​ display​ ​ 6*100/15​ ​ = ​ ​ 40%​ ​ for
Apples.

thanks in advance hope hear from you soon

[image]
i am new in python and i don't get idea how to handle each column in csv seprately
[image]

Comment: Please do not paste code and data screenshots into your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Define the columns you want to update:

```
fruit = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Pears", "Bananas"]
```

Check which values are greater than 50 (True or False?); sum up results (because `True` has the numerical value of 1); divide by the number of rows (the first element of the `shape` attribute); put the results into a new row.

```
df.loc['new', fruit] = (df[fruit] > 50).sum() / df.shape[0]
```

Comment: There will be no output. But the dataframe `df` changed. Didn't you want to change it? If you want to update the CSV file, you have to save the DataFrame into the file.

Comment: after saving i get result but it is different then what i expect

Comment: That's not helpful. How different is it? What did you expect and what did you get? Also, you still have not updated the question with textual code and data. I cannot know exactly what data you use.

Comment: in apple column 7 time value is greater then 50 so i expect output will be 7 but i got output 0.4666

Comment: You wrote in the question that you want the percentage of the outputs that are better than 50. 7/15 is 0.4666.

Comment: sir i have a question that can we rank column using a single row like we have percentage i.e. apples -- 46.66 and orange have 13.33 etc so can we rank column using the row values???

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: (x[x>50.].count())/x.count())
```

Comment: It won't - because of the non-numeric column 'Image Names'. Also, note that the original dataframe contains percentage points (0 through 100).